# WP Job Manager - display search results from custom search form in taxonomy-job_listing_category page

Tags: filters, taxonomy

i want to ask something about wp-job-manager plugin. i have been already created a taxonomy_job_listing_categoy template to list all jobs from a certain job category. You can see an example here: http://www.jobseeker.gr/job-category/pliroforiki/

i have also added a custom search form ( keywords + location ) for more filtering. What i want now is when trying a search query on this custom search form to return the search results in the same page and not redirecting to the [jobs] page. Below is the template i have:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

   <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
   <h1 class="page-title">Θέσεις εργασίας για <?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>

    <div id="content" role="main">
       <form  method="GET" action="">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Λέξη κλειδί" id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" />
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Τοποθεσία"   id="search_location" name="search_location" />
        <input class="search" type="submit"  value="Αναζήτηση" />
      </form>
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Alert' ) ) : ?>
            <!--Wigitized 'Alert' for the home page -->
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="job-listings">
                            <ul class="job_listings">
                              <?php global $post; ?>
                <li <?php job_listing_class(); ?> data-longitude="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->geolocation_lat ); ?>" data-latitude="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->geolocation_long ); ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_job_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_company_logo(); ?>
        <div class="position">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <div class="company">
                <?php the_company_name( '<strong>', '</strong> ' ); ?>
                <?php the_company_tagline( '<span class="tagline">', '</span>' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="location">
            <?php the_job_location( false ); ?>
        </div>
        <ul class="meta">
            <li class="job-type <?php echo get_the_job_type() ? sanitize_title( get_the_job_type()->slug ) : ''; ?>"><?php the_job_type(); ?></li>
            <li class="date"><date><?php printf( __( '%s πριν', 'wp-job-manager' ), human_time_diff( get_post_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></date></li>
                 <?php do_action( 'job_listing_meta_end' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
            </div><!--.job-listing-->
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

            <div class="no-results">
                <p><strong><?php _e('There has been an error.'); ?></strong></p>
                <p><?php _e('We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.'); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); /* outputs the default WordPress search form */ ?>
            </div><!--noResults-->
        <?php endif; ?>
              <?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) ); ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The problem is that when searching there is no results returning. What am i missing?

Best Regards,
Panos

Comment: Update info:
After searching i come to this code: `<form method="GET" action="">
     <div class="job_category_search_keywords">
 <input type="text" name="search_keywords" id="job_category_search_keywords" placeholder="Λέξη κλειδί, τίτλος ή εταιρεία" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $keywords ); ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="job-category">Αναζήτηση</button>
  <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
</form>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[jobs categories='.get_query_var('job_listing_category').' show_filters="false"]'); ?>`

Comment: You can see after the update an ex. http://www.jobseeker.gr/job-category/pliroforiki/

This is working fine. Two things only. The first is that the search query is not saving after submit button. The second the reset link is missing. I think is has to do with the ajax filters.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Please, use the [edit] link below the question to add additional info. Not everyone reads comments and they will be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the finally code that is working like  a chram

```
     <?php
     $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
     $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
     get_header(); ?>

     <h1 class="page-title">Θέσεις εργασίας για <?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>
        <div id="content">
       <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post'); ?>>

       <?php echo do_shortcode('[jobs categories='.get_query_var('job_listing_category').' show_filters="true"]'); ?>

       </article>
       </div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the callback that is attached to the shortcode instead? Works faster (no Regex involved) and is closer to the real API. Also: Please use English instead of foreign languages so everyone can read and understand your example.

Comment: @kaiser thank you for your comment. I don't know how to use the callback ( i am new to action hooks ) that's why. If you could provide this solution please you welcome to do it. I would happy to learn. I am sorry for the Greek's i have just forgotten translate to English.

Comment: You need to search up the [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) call in the plugin or theme that added it. The first argument is the shortcode name (that should be `jobs`) and the second argument is the callback. You can then simply use the callback directly. About the Greek: You can always [edit] questions and answers. It will be accepted asap (with more reputation points, you do not need review anymore). Just write a meaningful edit note :)